# Android sdk 3.2. Class.forName() problems

Tags: java, android

All i am doig is tyrying to switch from one window to the next but i keep getting errors. i have searched google and have not been able to figure out where im going wrong. i hope someone out there can tell me what is going on. here is the error log. Im getting a classnotfound but cant understand why. its in my manifest.

```
05-30 23:52:51.129: W/System.err(593): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jmedia.hvacanalizer.NEWCUSTOMER
05-30 23:52:51.149: W/System.err(593):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native >Method)
05-30 23:52:51.149: W/System.err(593):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:227)
05-30 23:52:51.149: W/System.err(593):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:174)
05-30 23:52:51.149: W/System.err(593):  at com.jmedia.hvacanalizer.HVACAnalizerActivity$1.onClick(HVACAnalizerActivity.java:30)
05-30 23:52:51.169: W/System.err(593):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
05-30 23:52:51.169: W/System.err(593):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
05-30 23:52:51.169: W/System.err(593):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-30 23:52:51.179: W/System.err(593):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 23:52:51.179: W/System.err(593):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-30 23:52:51.190: W/System.err(593):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-30 23:52:51.190: W/System.err(593):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 23:52:51.190: W/System.err(593):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-30 23:52:51.190: W/System.err(593):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-30 23:52:51.199: W/System.err(593):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-30 23:52:51.199: W/System.err(593):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 23:52:51.199: W/System.err(593): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jmedia.hvacanalizer.NEWCUSTOMER
05-30 23:52:51.212: W/System.err(593):  ... 15 more
05-30 23:52:51.219: W/System.err(593): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jmedia.hvacanalizer.NEWCUSTOMER in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jmedia.hvacanalizer-2.apk]

05-30 23:52:51.234: W/System.err(593):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
05-30 23:52:51.234: W/System.err(593):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
05-30 23:52:51.239: W/System.err(593):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
05-30 23:52:51.239: W/System.err(593):  ... 15 more
```

and here is the code from my manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jmedia.hvacanalizer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HVACAnalizerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".newcustomer"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.jmedia.hvacanalizer.NEWCUSTOMER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the code from my class...

```
public class HVACAnalizerActivity extends Activity {

    Button bNew, bLookUp;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        bNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewCustomer);
        bLookUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLUCustomer);
        bNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Class<?> newCustomerClass = Class.forName("com.jmedia.hvacanalizer.NEWCUSTOMER");
                    Intent newCustomerIntent = new Intent(
                            HVACAnalizerActivity.this, newCustomerClass);
                    startActivity(newCustomerIntent);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        bLookUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Class newCustomerClass = null;

            }
        });
    }
```

if someone can help me out here that would be great. this is my first attempt at coding for the android and im already about to pull my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a reference for others i want to post the answer. I was looking in the wrong spot. The problem was a coding error in the initialize method in the newcustomer class. I think it was where i had referenced the same button that is in my hvacanalizeractivity class by mistake. hope this helps other beginners like me.

Comment: +1 because it's always good to post your answer as a reference for others.   :-)